# How does trace autoflush affect tracing in multi-threaded .Net application?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, system.diagnostics

I have some problem getting the Trace functionality for TextWriterTraceListener working from inside other threads.  My code is as follows.

```
class Program
    {
        private static TraceSource mySource =
            new TraceSource("TraceSourceApp");
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Activity1();
            mySource.Close();

            Task.Run(() => mySource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 90, string.Format("log from thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)));

            return;
        }
        static void Activity1()
        {
            mySource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 1, "Error message2.");
            mySource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 2, "Warning message2.");
            mySource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 90, "Warning from main thread");
        }
    }
```

App.config

```
<sources>
  <source name="TraceSourceApp"
    switchName="sourceSwitch"
    switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
    <listeners>
      <add name="console"
        type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener">

      </add>
      <add name="myListener"/>
      <remove name="Default"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<switches>
  <add name="sourceSwitch" value="4"/>
</switches>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="myListener"
    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
    initializeData="myListener.log">

  </add>
</sharedListeners>
```

When I set autoflush=false, the trace added from non-UI thread is not generated in myListener.log file.  It works only when autoflush is true.  The trace can be seen in console though.  What could be reason for this?

Comment: You have a race condition. The `Task` created by `Run` may or may not finish by the time `Main` finishes execution.

Comment: Great catch!! You are right.  The trace was not logged because main thread had exited before logging was done.  I changed it like this - Task.Run(() => mySource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 90, string.Format("log from thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))).Wait();  It worked after waiting on new thread.  But I have a similar problem in WinForms app.  I am sure there main UI thread is not exiting before child threads finish.

Comment: Then show us the code for the UI.

Comment: I think I resolved the issue by changing correct switch configuration.  Perhaps I was using incorrect switchValue and switchType in my WinForms application.  Thank you for your answer.